# How to chain together jQuery animations slideUp and slideDown for two different elements

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

How would I modify the renderCalculator function to slideUp the recipes and slideDown the results of the recipe calculation? Both animation functions should be chained together. I saw answers for slideUp and SlideDown, but I'm not sure where to place the code in the function.

```
var renderCalculator = function(base) {
    var costHTML = $("<button>Calculate Weekly Total</button>");
    var resultsHTML = $("<div id='results'></div>");
    costHTML.on("click", function(event) {
        //total everything

        //grab all inputs on page
        $(".recipeSelector").each(function(i,input) {
            if (input.value > 0)
            {
                //figure out how many recipes were made
                a1.bakedRecipes.push({recipe:a1.recipes[input.id],amount:input.value});
            }
        });

        //print out required total information
        resultsHTML.empty(); //delete old info
        calculateAndPrintTotals(resultsHTML);       

    });
    base.append(costHTML);
    base.append(resultsHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just

```
$("#results").slideDown();
$(".recipeSelector").slideUp();
```

?

Did I miss something?

If you want first slideDomn `#results`, then slideUp `.recipe`, do this :

```js
$("#results").slideDown('slow', function(){
        $(".recipeSelector").slideUp();
    });
```

```css
#results{ display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"><h1>RESULTS</h1></div>
<div class="recipeSelector"><h1>RECIPE</h1></div>
<div class="recipeSelector"><h1>RECIPE</h1></div>
<div class="recipeSelector"><h1>RECIPE</h1></div>
```

Comment: Where would I place $("#results").slideDown('slow', function(){
        $(".recipeSelector").slideUp();
    });

Comment: Uh, where you want the animation to happen, of course... Like in your click function.

Comment: What does your console say? Any errors? Try to console.log stuff.

Comment: I have added a second answer.

Comment: Frankly, I don't know how it's supposed to look. The results appear below the recipe info, but it doesn't look like they're sliding.

Answer (score 1):

I actually rewrote it my way =) If it does what you want it to do, the code is not even 30 lines high.

See it here in action : http://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/JowaQj

I wrote it in Coffeescript (which is then compiled into javascript), you can toggle original code and compiled code with the small "eye" icon at the top, in codepen.

I have also modified the data object, made the structure simpler and easier to manipulate.

```
$ul = $("ul.wrapper")

for recipe in data.recipes
    template = "<li><h2>"+recipe.name+"</h2>"

    cost = 0

    for ingredient, quantity of recipe.ingredients
        template += "<p>"+ingredient+" : "+quantity+"</p>"
        cost += quantity * data.products[ingredient].cost // calculating recipe cost on the fly

    template += "How many "+recipe.name+" should be baked?"
    template += " <input type='number' value='0' data-cost='"+cost+"' />" # Storing the cost of one recipe in the input itself. Then, we just have to multiply that by the quantity
    template +="</li>"

    $ul.append template



$("button").click ->
    totalCost = 0

    $("input[type=number]").each ->
        cost = parseFloat($(this).data('cost'))
        qty = parseInt($(this).val())
        totalCost += cost * qty

    $("span.amount").text totalCost
    $("h2").slideDown()
    $ul.slideUp()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it from your JSfiddle. Click doesn't do anything because you CREATE a button instead of selecting the existing one.

`var costHTML = $("<button>Calculate Weekly Total</button>")` actually *creates* a new jQuery object in the browser's memory. If you want to select the existing one, use :

In the HTML :

```
<button id="btn-calculate">Calculate Weekly Total</button>
```

In the JS :

```
$("#btn-calculate").click( function(){
     alert("Button clicked!");

     $("#results").slideDown('slow', function(){
        $(".recipeSelector").slideUp();
     });
});
```

Comment: Should I still leave     var costHTML = $("<button>Calculate Weekly Total</button>") there?

Comment: The problem is, I'm not sure what you want to do. I get it you want to hide stuff, show stuff, but based on what? Moreover, the code is 320 lines high...

Comment: I would like the renderCalculator function to slideUp the recipes and slideDown the results of the recipe calculation.  This is for a class assignment.  I assume the recipes that are already there should slide up, & then the calculations (results) should slide down.

Comment: Actually, your code is just......... wow. `$(".recipeSelector").each(function(i,input) {` is a nonsense. The second argument you'll get is not an input, it's a `.recipeSelector`... You can't access inputs this way... Then, there is nothing with a class of `.recipeSelector` at all in your HTML. The class of the recipes is `.recipe`. So trying to select `.recipeSelector` is a waste of time because there is none :) Then in a `each` loop, you hide all elements of a class. I mean, I would need days to figure out what this code is trying to do... I would actually rewrite everything from scratch!

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway.  I thought it would have been a quick one.  You've helped me quite a bit already.  I appreciate your help & patience today.

Comment: It is a quick one. I don't understand why it requires 320 lines, an "engine" and stuff. It's just a few line of script. I rewrote it my way and posted a 3rd answer.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error of placing the code in different locations, this worked:

```
$(".recipe").slideUp('slow', function() {
    resultsHTML.empty(); //delete old info
    calculateAndPrintTotals(resultsHTML);
    $("#results").slideDown('slow');
    });
```